# Sorting percentiles aggregation with NaN values

Tags: elasticsearch, nan, percentile, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using ElasticSearch 2.3.3 and I have the following aggregation:

```
"aggregations": {
        "mainBreakdown": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "location_i",
                "size": 10,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "comments>medianTime.50": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "comments": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "type_i": 120
                        }
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "medianTime": {
                            "percentiles": {
                                "field": "time_l",
                                "percents": [
                                    50.0
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for better understanding I've added to field names a postfix which tells the field mapping:

- _i = integer
- _l = long (timestamp)

And aggregation response is:

```
"aggregations": {
    "mainBreakdown": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 100,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "comments": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "medianTime": {
              "values": {
                "50.0": 20113
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 121,
          "doc_count": 14,
          "comments": {
            "doc_count": 0,
            "medianTime": {
              "values": {
                "50.0": "NaN"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `medianTime` aggregation, sometimes has value of `NaN` because the parent aggregation `comments` has 0 matched documents, and then the result with the `NaN` will always be last on both "asc" and "desc" order.
I've tried adding `"missing": 0` inside `percentiles` aggregation but it still returns a `NaN`.

Can you please help me sorting my buckets by medianTime that and when it's "asc" ordering the `NaN` values will be first and when its "desc" they will be last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN's are not numbers, so they will always be last.
After a short discussion on elasticsearch github, we decided its the appropriate way to handle NaN's.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/36402